# Device Error when lunching a emulator in xamarin visual studio. How can I solve it?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

After adding my device ( Pixel 2 Pie 9.0 API-28) This error log is shown. I manage and configure sdk manger. After that I install Hyper V for emulating third party emulator for visual studio. Everything was ok but when I lunch my device this error is showing. What is the problem and can you show me any solution to solve this?

I tried to reset device manger or delete devices. But that doesn't work. 
This is my Error log.

```
Device error: emulator: Android virtual device file at: C:\Users\DELL\.android\avd\pixel_2_pie_9_0_api_28.ini
emulator: virtual device content at C:\Users\DELL\.android\avd\pixel_2_pie_9_0_api_28.avd
emulator: virtual device config file: C:\Users\DELL\.android\avd\pixel_2_pie_9_0_api_28.avd\config.ini
emulator: using core hw config path: C:\Users\DELL\.android\avd\pixel_2_pie_9_0_api_28.avd\hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: using snapshot lock path: C:\Users\DELL\.android\avd\pixel_2_pie_9_0_api_28.avd\snapshot.lock
emulator: using multi-instance lock path: C:\Users\DELL\.android\avd\pixel_2_pie_9_0_api_28.avd\multiinstance.lock
emulator: Found AVD target API level: 28
emulator: Read property file at C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-28\google_apis_playstore\x86\\build.prop 
...
...
...
emulator: Concatenated backend parameters:
 '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe"' -verbose -feature WindowsHypervisorPlatform -avd pixel_2_pie_9_0_api_28 -prop emu.uuid=5b4f3ed6-3bd5-45c9-a093-06751e03b091
```

I really want to know how to resolve it.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to debug the app on a real device ? And run the  Android Virtual Device (AVD) Manager as administrator.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT yeah but that doesn't work. After I delete bin file and downgrade NuGet, emulator is working. But it says "UI stops working". I dont know why!

Comment: Try to create a new project and check if the error still appears.

Comment: Open sdk manager and make sure under API 28 system images are installed.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to uninstall and reinstall API 28 and any corresponding files and SDKs. Either that or beside the apply changes button in the SDK there should be a button for repair. Click that and allow it to run.

Answer (score 0):

I simply replaced the existing Mono.Posix.dll with the latest version of Mono.Posix.dll, to do so copy the .dll to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Xamarin.VisualStudio and it started working for me, you can get the latest Mono.Posix.dll from https://www.dllme.com/dll/files/mono_posix_dll.html

Comment: please visit and check [how to answer a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The Android Device Manager asked me if i want to reinstall i said yes, clicked accept and that was all (It make take a couple of minutes so be patient)

[image]